# Match between word and 6th occurance of slash (/) with Regex

Tags: regex

I have troubles matching text between a word *pages* and 6th slash which occurs before *HomeGardenerTools*.

**I want to transform this to:**

https://facebook.com/pages/category/Home---Garden-Store/HomeGardenerTools

**To this:**

https://facebook.com/pg/HomeGardenerTools

What I have thus far is start of selection:

```
pages(.?)
```

and matching anything before 6th slash:

```
^((?:[^/]*/){6})
```

Comment: `(.*?)pages\/((.*?)\/){2}(.*)` and replace with `$1pg/$4` See https://regex101.com/r/J67dZR/1

Comment: See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sHxMav/2). `pages\/(?:[^\/]+\/){2}` => `pg/`

Comment: That sadly matches the whole string.

Comment: That worked Wiktor. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
pages\/(?:[^\/]+\/){2}
```

And replace with `pg/`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sHxMav/2).

**Details**

- `pages\/` - a `pages/` substring
- `(?:[^\/]+\/){2}` -  two repetitions of

  - `[^\/]+` - 1 or more chars other than `/`
  - `\/` - a `/` char.